# Is there a way to clean up Hjerim after the 1.4 patch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

According to UESP, the [1.4 patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.4.21.0.4) included a fix for the "...issue where the player house in Windhelm would not clean up properly".

However, after applying the update and loading a game where I'd already completed Blood on the Ice and fully upgraded Hjerim, my house is still a mess!

Is there anything that needs to be done to trigger the cleanup?  Or, is this something that is only fixed for new games or games where the quest has not yet been completed?

Comment: Talk to the steward. If the option isn't there, you're screwed.

Comment: Why don't you guys post those as actual answers?  I'll accept what works.

Answer (score 1):

The fix only applies to saves where you haven't yet encountered the bug. If you're playing on PC, you can use the console command `DF492.disable` to clean up the mess.

Answer (score 0):

First finish the quest. If already finished, talk with the Windhelm's Stewart and look in the upgrade menu. It should be only 500 Septims and if you get the arcane enchanter and the alchemy lab they are put in that room.

If the Stewart doesn't have the clean up the butchers mess option then theres no way to do it